# Client training scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduling

I'm looking for a training planner software that allows me to customize my training schedule per customer, on the fly.

I'd like to arrange training per module. Each module contains multiple training resources, and I wouldn't want to have to rearrange each specific one each time I change the date or set up a schedule. I'd like to just quickly adjust module training dates, and with that, all the resources would change too

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [base2race](http://www.base2race.com)?
It has a very good presetation, with calendar and time scheduling that you can set as you need.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMVL07NaaHw) than can ilustrate you.